# x86 assembly - CMP not setting zero flag correctly

Tags: assembly, x86, compare, cmp, eflags

I came across this compare when debugging:

```
| 38 19 | CMP BYTE PTR DS:[ECX], BL
```

I set a breakpoint on it and saw this (values in **hex**):

```
ECX = 00838430
BYTE PTR[ECX]=[00838430]=55
EBX = 00000055 (BL = 55)
EFLAGS = 00000314 (CF=0 OF=0 SF=0 ZF=0 AF=1 PF=1)
```

So I expected the zero flag to be set after executing this compare, since the byte pointed to by ECX and BL are equal. However, what happened instead was that the overflow flag was set and ZF remained 0. After the compare:

```
EFLAGS = 00000A06 (CF=0 OF=1 SF=0 ZF=0 AF=0 PF=1)
```

Why does it behave like this? Does it have something to do with signed/unsigned integers? I thought CMP was agnostic, i.e. interpreting the result of the compare as signed/unsigned was something the following branch instruction would do (e.g. JG vs JA). The compare is followed by a JNE which is taken because ZF=0 and is causing incorrect results.

Comment: Usually the `CMP` does set the flags correctly, and the values you did show indicate the ZF should be set, so I'm 99% sure one of the values you did describe is incorrect. I would verify the memory content first, are you sure there is 55 at `ds:[ecx]`? How did you get that number? Is this 32b mode with flat memory model (ds = not important then)?

Comment: Please remember that `CMP` *does* set the flags correctly. Blame the code, not the processor.

Comment: Well, technically you may have damaged CPU producing incorrect flags after `CMP`, but unless that's a one-time mishap of wandering electron due to X-ray collision/etc. (can happen, with the amount of HW in everydays life the chance is that at least few currently living humans will at least once in their life encounter such situation... although they will very likely not notice), it would produce so many bad results, that you would never get that far as booting your OS and running debugger... So if you don't believe the `cmp`, try it like one more time and that's it, search for problem around.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

<s>I suspected there was some kind of bug in the debugger, so I tried with another one (OllyDbg v2) and saw that the values I posted were indeed correct, there was 55 in memory and in BL. However, running under Olly, the CMP behaved correctly like expected, that is, ZF was set and the jump not taken.</s>

So the code is actually working as intended, the problem is with the debugger. When the code is not running under a debugger, it works correctly as well. For this particular code, it's a bit difficult and time consuming to test the correctness without a debugger, which is why I never tested it without a debugger so far. The bug is not with a breakpoint or single-stepping since it didn't work correctly when just being run either.

The debugger with the bug is x64dbg (despite the name, it's not only for 64-bit). My build is a bit outdated already, maybe the bug is fixed in the latest snapshot.

Thanks for the comments everyone.

---

It was actually user error and not a bug in the debugger. There was an INT3 breakpoint set at 00838430 that I forgot about or maybe I forgot for a moment how software breakpoints work. Anyway, the actual content of the memory in that case was 0xCC, but the debugger showed the original byte. So the CMP behaved exactly like it should have. Ped7g was right from the first comment that I should double-check the memory content. The second test with another debugger worked correctly only because I didn't set a breakpoint at 00838430 then.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/G3kaY.jpg